# how to use psd templates in netbeans IDE

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, psd

i get psd file form this link [60 Free UI Design Kits](http://mag.splashnology.com/article/60-free-ui-design-kits-templates-and-resources/853/)

but i whant to use in my netbeans GUI .

so how can i add this templates in my netbeans IDE palette.

Comment: Java doesn't natively support psd files. If support bmp, jpg, gif and png though

Answer (score 0):

You can't, NetBeans doesn't support `.PSD` files.

However you can download a photo editor like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), or another program that can open PhotoShop files, and convert the `.PSD` into something that NetBeans can use, like a `.jpg` or `.png`.